# Find the languages/platform used by apps on my Android device

Tags: android

I am curious to know the languages and platform used in development of apps 
 installed on my Android mobile.

1. Is there way to know this?
2. Is there an easy way to know languages of Android app not even installed on my device?
3. Can I know from Play Store which languages are used for the development ?

Comment: I don't see why this question is being downvoted, it's pretty clear and could be interesting for other people ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there way to know this?

Not in general.

> Is there an easy way to know languages of Android app not even installed on my device?

No.

> Can I know from Play Store which languages are used for the development

No.

If the developers of the app offer some form of support channel, ask them what they used.

Comment: Your answer is clear but I don't really know the road is blocked. Asking to developers is the suggestion you suggested. I will accept your answer once few more replies or upvotes your answer receive.